# Setting state through REST API

Tags: api, rest

Is there a convention for exposing a state update function to the API consumer?

I have a /orders endpoint, where each order can have some states e.g.:
1 - Submitted
2 - Pending
3 - Shipped

Customers can submit orders, but then staff will eventually have their own GUI to change order state.

I'm wondering, for a particular order e.g. `/orders/123`, would it be better to consume the API using `PUT /orders/123` with `{state: 2}`.

Or would it be better to expose some convenience functions such as `GET /orders/pending` that would handle setting state for the API consumer?

Comment: GET requests should not change internal state of your data, so if you want to have `GET /orders/pending` that will update order's state that is bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common practice is to use `GET` requests as read-only data access, and `PUT` requests to set state, updates, and other data write operations.

Aside from being common, this practice has the added benefit of being intuitive, and relays the intent of the API and client code that's accessing the API really well.

Note, however, that `PUT` verb is really meant to *replace* a resource in full, not for updating any single property of a resource. There's another HTTP verb for that - `PATCH` - which would be better suited for your case.

Rather than creating yet another copy of HTTP verbs reference, I'd like to refer you to [this tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html), which I found quite excellent and thorough. Take a look at both `PUT` and `PATCH` verbs to make a decision for your implementation.

Comment: PUT requests are meant to replace/create a resource, not partially update, that's PATCH

Comment: @TimCastelijns that's a good point; I was addressing the specific HTTP verbs referenced in the original question, but you're absolutely right, and I'll update my answer to reflect `PATCH` shortly.